# property_tree get array value as String

Tags: c++, json, c++11, boost

I want to parse a json file/string with boosts property_tree, but instead of having sub-trees parsed into an array I would like it to stay as a string for use in another existing function which only deals with json-Strings.

I hope the following example is sufficient:

---

example.json

```
{
    "type": "myType",
    "colors": {
        "color0":"red",
        "color1":"green",
        "color2":"blue"
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
std::stringstream ss("example.json");
ptree pt;
read_json(ss, pt);

std::string sType = pt.get("type", "");
std::string sColors = pt.get<std::string>("colors");

std::cout << "sType: " << sType << std::endl; // sType: myType
std::cout << "sColors: " << sColors << std::endl; // sColors: {"color0":"red", "color1":"green", "color2":"blue"}
```

---

I've tried several functions, for example `pt.get_child("colors")` would just return another ptree and `pt.get_value<std::string>("colors")` does return an empty string `("")`.

The desired output would look like this:

```
sColors: {"color0":"red", "color1":"green", "color2":"blue"}
```

or

```
sColors: {\"color0\":\"red\", \"color1\":\"green\", \"color2\":\"blue\"}
```

Is there a way to recive the desired output for sColors?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution faster than anticipated, the following code will provide a satisfactory answer:

```
std::stringstream os;
write_json(os, pt.get_child("colors"), false);
std::string sColors = os.str();
std::cout << "sColors: " << sColors << std::endl;
```

If there is a more elegant solution feel free to post it as well!